# How to Set the Background Color of SAPUI5 sap.m.StandardTreeItem?

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I would like to set a custom color of `sap.m.Tree items`. Looking other examples in `sap.m.List`, I implemented `onAfterRendering` of `sap.m.StandardTreeItem`:

```
snip
    sap.m.StandardTreeItem.extend('MySuperDuperTreeItem', {
     metadata: {
     properties: {
         status: 'string'
     }
     },      
     onAfterRendering: function() {
     if (sap.m.StandardTreeItem.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
         sap.m.StandardTreeItem.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
     }
     //var a = getItem(); NOT WORKING
     this.$().find('div').each(function() {
         if ($(this).hasClass('sapMCbBg')) {
         $(this).addClass("myPurple");
         }
     });
     },
     renderer:{}

 });
```

I have put an example [here](https://jsbin.com/vujuday/edit?html,output).

From the JSBin link, you can see the check boxes have a custom color, but I would like to set their color based on item's title. Also, the tree item detail button is not properly displayed an expand and collapse.

Is there an alternative way to color check boxes? 
Why it is not possible to access `sap.m.StandardTreeItem` members (like `getTitle()`) in onAfterRendering function?

Comment: "this.getTitle()" - in onAfterRendering. What do you mean by "inproper displaying" of the detail button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **this.getTitle()** in the **onAfterRendering** method to get the title. And based on that title you can add your style class based on the title as below

```
    onAfterRendering: function() {
         sap.m.StandardTreeItem.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
         var title = this.getTitle();
         this.$().find('div').each(function() {
             if ($(this).hasClass('sapMCbBg')) {
               if (jQuery.sap.startsWith(title, "A-Node")) {
                 $(this).addClass("myPurple");
               } else if (jQuery.sap.startsWith(title, "B-Node")) {
                 $(this).addClass("myYellow");
               }
             }
         });
     }
```

And the thing about the tree item detail button is not properly displayed an expand and collapse, you have to just modify your code little bit as below

```
 var oStandardTreeItem = new MySuperDuperTreeItem({
     title: "{text}",
     type: sap.m.ListType.Detail
 });
 oTree.bindItems("/", oStandardTreeItem);
 oTree.expandToLevel(3);
 oTree.setMode(sap.m.ListMode.MultiSelect);
 var oPage = new sap.m.Page("TreeTest", {
     title : "Test Page for sap.m.Tree",
     content : [oTree]
 });
```

Here is the [link](https://jsbin.com/tubojaguji/1/edit?html,output) that renders the check boxes with different colors based on the title.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my example and for the additional info!

Comment: I have another related question. How do I prevent blue coloring on selected tree item?

Comment: I made an example [link][https://jsbin.com/sisijazuso/edit?html,output#jade]. It works as I want, when you manually select item, but the coloring of row is still there when item is selected at the creation time.

Comment: I just realized that the link was not valid. Here is the working one [link](https://jsbin.com/zufixo/edit?html,output). Maybe this should be posted as a separate issue.